# Rotating an image by x angle in c

Tags: c, image, rotation

I am rotating the image by x(45 degres) angle, But I am getting some black spots in the rotated image.

How to avoid those black spots!!

The logic I have used as below

```
double sinx = sin((M_PI/4)*(180.0/M_PI));  //45 degrees
double cosx = cos((M_PI/4)*(180.0/M_PI));

xCenter = height/2;        // Rotate image by its center.
yCenter = width/2;

for(x=0; x<height; x++) {
    for(y=0; y<width; y++) {

        xt = x-xCenter; yt=y-yCenter;
        xRotate = (int) round( ((xt*cosx)-(yt*sinx)) + xCenter );
        yRotate = (int) round( ((yt*cosx)+(xt*sinx)) + yCenter );   

        if( (x >= 0) && (x < height) && (y >= 0) && (y < width) ) {
                rotatedImage[xRotate][yRotate] = inputImage[x][y];
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You calculate the position in the rotated image X' from each pixel in the original image X, but you should do it the other way round: For each pixel in the rotated image X' calculate the respective position in the original image and copy it if it exists, that is if it isn't outside the original image. That way you have every pixel in X' covered.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than looping over the un-rotated image's pixels, loop over the rotated image instead. This will mean you won't miss pixels due to rounding the rotated coordinates to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`sin((M_PI/4)*(180.0/M_PI));` is not the the sine of "45 degrees".  It is the sine of 45 radians. Same about `double cosx`

Suggest `double sinx = sin(45.0/180.0*M_PI);`

---

Also consider `lround()` vs. `(int) round()`.

Further, the range of `xRotate, yRotate` is about sqrt(2) time more than the range of `height, width`.  Code should watch out for integer overflow when converting from `double`.

---

Iterate as answered by [@Chris Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187921/2410359) and commented by [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187855/rotating-an-image-by-x-angle-in-c/53193215#comment93265035_53187855)

Below uses OP-like code but with a -45 rotation as code is mapping *from* `inputImage`.

```
#defined SIND(a) (sin((a)/180.0 * M_PI)
#defined COSD(a) (cos((a)/180.0 * M_PI)
double sinx = SIND(-45);  // -degrees
double cosx = COSD(-45);

xCenter = height;        // Rotate image by its center.
yCenter = width;

for(x=0; x<height; x++) {
    xt = x - xCenter;
    double xt_cosx = xt*cosx;
    double xt_sinx = xt*sinx;
    for(y=0; y<width; y++) {
        yt = y - yCenter;
        long xRotate = lround(xt_cosx - (yt*sinx)) + xCenter;
        long yRotate = lround((yt*cosx) + xt_sinx) + yCenter;   

        if( (xRotate >= 0) && (xRotate < height) && (yRotate >= 0) && (yRotate < width) ) {
          rotatedImage[x][y] = inputImage[xRotate][yRotate];
        } else {
          rotatedImage[x][y] = Default_Pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that looping over the rotated image with the **inverse** transform matrix of rotation according to meet the EMPATHY of coordinate transformation.

This is sample code for your reference.

```
void rotate(uint8_t* dst, uint8_t* src, int w, int h, int depth, int theta) {
if (depth != 8) {
    printf("Only support 8bits image !\n");
    return;
}
memset(dst, 0, sizeof(uint8_t)*w*h);
float phi = theta/180.0*PI;
float T_inv[2][2] = { cos(phi),  sin(phi),
                      -sin(phi), cos(phi)};
int i_;
int j_;
int center_i = round(w/2.0);
int center_j = round(h/2.0);

//v' = Tinv * v
for (int j=0; j<h; j++) {
    for (int i=0; i<w; i++) {
        i_ = round(T_inv[0][0]*(i-center_i) + T_inv[0][1]*(j-center_j)) + center_i;
        j_ = round(T_inv[1][0]*(i-center_i) + T_inv[1][1]*(j-center_j)) + center_j;
        if (i_ < 0 || j_ < 0)
            continue;
        if (i_ >= w)
            continue;
        if (j_ >= h)
            continue;
        dst[i+j*w] = src[i_+j_*w];
    }
}
return;
}
```